# Why does C not decrement the stack pointer if a variable leaves the scope?

Tags: c, stack-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    {
        int x;
        printf("%p\n", &x);
    }
    {
        int x;
        printf("%p\n", &x);
    }
}
```

I would think running this that it would output the same thing twice. When it declares the first variable, it increments the stack pointer, but then leaves the scope, so it decrements it, and then just repeats the process the second time, so `int x` would occupy the same memory location on the stack both times.

But this isn't the case. The stack pointer is not decremented and `int x` in both cases occupy different locations in the stack. In fact, the first `int x` is still reachable even though its scope is gone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    {
        int x = 10;
        printf("%p\n", &x);
    }
    {
        int x = 25;
        printf("%p\n", &x);
    }
    {
        int x = 71;
        printf("%p\n", &x);

        int *p = &x;
        printf("%i %i %i\n", *(p + 2), *(p + 1), *p);
    }
}
```

Why is this? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Because it doesn't have to? Allocating all of the local variables at once is giving less performance overhead than moving it back and forth for every block.

Comment: C standard does not mention any stack. It's possible that enough memory is reserved on the stack at the start of the function. It's unusual to push and pop variables on demand: there is a stack frame.

Comment: It might behave differently with optimisations enabled, recycling locations in the stack frame.

Comment: Because what it does with the stack is none of your business. You may get different results with another compiler or with different compiler settings.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that local variables were always removed from the stack when it was out of scope. I did try different optimisation settings and it does change the output, so now I understand a bit better what the compiler is doing. Thanks.

Comment: @AmeliaHartman From the C programmer perspective these variables cease to exist, even though the memory might be still unused by anything else, so any reference to them will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard does not even mention a stack. The compiler is free to optimize variables away when they are not needed. There is absolutely nothing in the C standard that implies that the printouts should be neither equal or not equal.

On my computer, this manifests itself by giving different output depending on optimization level:

```
$ gcc c.c

/tmp$ ./a.out 
0x7ffd8733c3ac
0x7ffd8733c3a8

/tmp$ gcc c.c -O3

/tmp$ ./a.out 
0x7fff4e91544c
0x7fff4e91544c
```

> In fact, the first "int x" is still reachable even though its scope is gone.

Accessing a variable that has gone out of scope causes *undefined behavior*, which means that anything can happen. This includes the case where the program works as intended.

Here is the output from your second snippet with different optimizations:

```
/tmp$ ./a.out 
0x7ffd4df94864
0x7ffd4df94860
0x7ffd4df9485c
10 25 71

/tmp$ gcc c.c -O3

/tmp$ ./a.out 
0x7ffc30b4e44c
0x7ffc30b4e44c
0x7ffc30b4e44c
0 0 71
```

When you get different behavior depending on optimization level, that's an almost 100% sign that your program has something that is causing undefined behavior. There is a very, very small chance that you have encountered a bug in the compiler. And apart from those two reasons, I cannot think of anything else that could be the cause.

Comment: In the C standard, “undefined behavior” does not mean anything can happen. It means the C standard imposes no requirements on the behavior. These are different things.

Comment: Which in turn means that the compiler is completely free to produce any code it wants, so yes, the resulting program can be anything, even if some scenarios are way more likely than others. Still, in the end it's basically the same. You destroy the predictability of the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What could possibly be the practical difference?

Comment: No, the resulting program cannot be anything. It is restricted by physics, logic, compiler specification, operating system specification, electrical safety regulations, and more. If “anything” could happen, then it would impossible to use the observed behavior to help figure out what went wrong. But experienced programmers learn to recognize symptoms and clues. One type of output suggests memory corruption, another suggests misinterpreted data, and so on. So that is one practical difference: “Anything” is not debuggable, but “not specified by C standard” is debuggable.

Comment: Another practical difference is that what is “undefined behavior” in the C standard may be a defined and supported language extension in a C implementation. For some extensions, using them **requires** you to write a program whose behavior is not defined by the standard. If the fact there were “undefined behavior” in the C standard’s meaning meant anything can happen, then the extension could not work—it could not be supported code. It is the fact that the C standard says **it**, and it alone, does not define the behavior that makes it possible to extend the C language so flexibly.

Comment: "Obey the laws of physic"? Are you for real? If I said that the program `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { puts("Hello World"); }` will print "Hello World", would you then say *"No, no, no, you cannot say that with 100% certainty. The compiler might have a bug. It can be something wrong with the hardware. Natural radioactivity might flip a bit in the memory. The operating system might run out of memory. Someone might pull the plug in the middle of the execution. So this program is not guaranteed to print 'Hello World'."*?

Comment: *"If “anything” could happen, then it would impossible to use the observed behavior to help figure out what went wrong."* - And just to continue on that track, this is also actually a logical flaw. In order for this to be true, you have to make assumptions about the probability distribution among the different events.

Comment: There is a very (very, very, very, very) small probability that the computer (or you, or basically everything else) will get spontaneously quantum teleported to Mars (or somewhere else). And actually, your fingerprint on your coffee mug might get quantum teleported to a murder weapon on the other side of earth. Does that mean that we cannot draw conclusions from finger prints on murder weapons? Of course not.

Comment: [Bit flips due to radiation](https://www.wnycstudios.org/story/bit-flip) are a serious concern. Such a bit flip is believed to have altered initially reported election results in one case, and, as a consequence, redundancy was added to vote counting. Bit flips from radiation are also a cause of [using purer materials in chip packaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error#Alpha_particles_from_package_decay). So, what you treat as a joke is a serious concern. If you want to do the best engineering, you have to deal with this. The reason you can often neglect it now is because other…

Comment: … people have already done the work to reduce the error levels significantly.

Comment: Let’s stick to the point, though. The sentence in this answer that says “Accessing a variable that has gone out of scope causes *undefined behavior*, which means that anything can happen” is false. It is provably false logically, factually, and practically. A false statement misinforms readers and makes the answer less useful. In particular, it leads students to falsely believe “undefined behavior” in the meaning of the C standard cannot be a part of C programs, but it is actually required for some extensions.…

Comment: …  And it is pointless since it is easy to state the truth instead, which is that “undefined behavior” means the C standard imposes no requirements on the behavior. An answer that teaches something false is not a good answer. It would be very easy to correct your answer so that the statement it makes is true instead of false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm perfectly aware that bitflips is a serious concern. My objection is that it is not worth mentioning when someone asks "What is the output of this program?". I can give you that you have a point that it might (but maybe not always) be worth mentioning that UB usually follows some kind of pattern that can give you clues and that many compiler extensions are UB, but I'm pretty sure that everybody (by which I exclude extreme cases) will understand that no program will defy logic or laws of physics. Mentioning that is completely superfluous.

Comment: First, nobody is asking you to mention in the answer that bit flips can occur or to state that no program will defy logic or laws of physics. The only request is that you change the false statement to a true statement. The statements about some situations in which there are differences were presented only at your request, to explain to you why it matters. Second, the statement is false. That alone is enough reason to fix it. It can be seen to false by looking up the definition of “undefined behavior” in the C standard., and it is known to be false for the reasons I have given.

Comment: Third, the statement induces false beliefs in readers. It misleads them to believe that “undefined behavior” must be avoided. That is wrong. The C standard defines a core language (of strictly conforming programs) and invites extensions (of conforming programs). Some of those extensions lie in the region that the C standard classifies as “undefined behavior” in its meaning. To understand C fully, one must understand that “undefined behavior” is actually a necessary part of the extended language, not something that should be always avoided.

Comment: I could fix it by changing it to "anything may happen, except for things that obviously cannot happen" but I don't see the point of doing that. Furthermore, while what you are saying is technically true and also important in many cases, I believe that mentioning these things every time UB is mentioned just clutters the answer and confuses people.

Comment: Once again, nobody is asking you to mention these things. Just to say “… undefined behavior, which means the C standard imposes not requirements” (or, if you feel that is too technical for a particular question’s level, “… undefined behavior, which means the C standard does not say what the program will do”). And the statement “anything may happen, except for things that obviously cannot happen” is also false, so you should not use that.

Comment: In my opinion, that does not highlight the dangers of UB enough. I think it makes more sense to say something that is not 100% correct, but teaches people that UB can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

As a practical matter, when a stack does exist (as Broman's answer points out, there is no requirement for a stack to exist, although there *is* a requirement to support recursion) compilers will typically generate code that adjusts the stack pointer only once on function entry, and once again on function exit, even if there are sub-scopes within the function that limit individual variables' lifetimes.

This might seem bizarre if you're used to writing assembly language by hand.  The most basic reason for it is, it means each variable that lives on the stack has a "stack slot" with a *fixed location* throughout the entire function, which gives the compiler maximum flexibility in moving machine instructions around for optimization.